# How to fix orientation after Healthkit permission screen?

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin.ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I added Healthkit specialty and Watch app support for my app. After this change, the orientation of the app is broken. My app only supports landscape orientation but it seems the Health app only supports portrait mode. After the Health app's permission screen at the beginning, my app's orientation was broken and the place of the keyboard was wrong. It is the same place as a portrait app.

I fixed this issue with changing orientation manually after the Health app permission screen but is there any better way to fix this problem?